# Cannot remove file after running Docker

Tags: docker, file, share, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have WSL and Docker for Windows installed and I typically used docker as follow:

```
docker run -v "$(pwd -P):/srv" -w/srv image make
```

When I run on my container things such as `npm init` or `sphinxbuild` I sometime have files created that I cannot remove once the container is terminated.

For the current case I was running Python sphinx and it created a file `_build/doctrees/environment.pickle` that I cannot remove unless I restart my computer. When I look at the permissions I can read

> You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings

However, I am running this panel in administrator mode.

So two questions:

- Why docker sometime create such corrupted files?
- How to prevent docker to do this?

Comment: are you sure that the container is not present anymore (running or stopped)? Docker runs in a VM so most probably the files you see are synchronized with that VM. What are you using for virtualization?

Comment: @Mihai I've killed Docker. The problem is the permissions not that the file is opened by anyone.

Comment: If it was a permissions issue then it shouldn't be fixed by restarting the computer.